# Cant find kubernetes bottleneck

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, locust

I am working on a project which has a goal to compare two architectures, monolithic and microservice. I built both apps, they both work fine, but the issue is in kubernetes. The app is a basic springboot app with H2 database. I test it using locust so I could show that monolithic cannot be scaled as well as microservice. When I run app on InteliJ, I can get locust up to 2000 RPS (request per second). Which means locust is not the bottleneck. When I run the app in a Docker Desktop, it is around 350RPS and the number doesnt even move (no errors or anything). When I boot the project in minikube, the app always stops at 122 RPS, no matter if it's monolithic or microservice, always 122, then errors start to rise up(ConnectionRefusedError(10061, '[WinError 10061] & RetriesExceeded('http://localhost:63254/account/1', 1, original=timed out) ). The main issue is that doesnt matter what I do with the pods, if I increase number of pods to 10, number is still 122, so I cannot prove my point of scaling the apps. I am running the minikube cluster on windows.

**DockerFile**

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim as builder
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} application.jar
RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar application.jar extract

FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim
COPY --from=builder dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder spring-boot-loader/ ./
#COPY --from=builder internal-dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder snapshot-dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder application/ ./
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]
```

**Deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: monolit-app-deployment   # Change the deployment name to monolit-app-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: monolit-app   # Change the app name to monolit-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: monolit-app   # Change the app name to monolit-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: monolit-cnt   # Change the container name to monolit-cnt
          image: sonntdav00/test:1.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
#          resources:
#            requests:
#              cpu: "6  # 500 milliCPU (0.5 CPU core)
#              memory: "6Gi"  # 512 megabytes
#            limits:
#              cpu: "6"  # 1 CPU core
#              memory: "6Gi"  # 1 gigabyte
          # Add environment variables if required
          # env:
          #   - name: ENV_VARIABLE_NAME
          #     value: ENV_VARIABLE_VALUE
          # Add any additional configuration or resource limits if needed


---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: monolit-app-service   # Change the service name to monolit-app-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: monolit-app   # Change the app name to monolit-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
  #      nodePort: 32000 # Specify the desired port here
  type: NodePort
```

**Locust monolith test**
[image]

Since I am running it on windows I thought that the issue is that WSL doesnt have enought computing power, so Increased the computing power of minikube to 15GB a 6 CPU (still no change, always stays on 122 RPS)

Comment: Also for locust testing I am using only GET methods, in order to keep the test simple.

Comment: also turned off Windows Defender in case he was doing something wrong